# Can't make python urllib urlretrieve work. Resulting image is corrupted

Tags: python

I've successfully written a code that go through several urls, find a specific image in each of them, and saves its address. now i want to download the image.

I'm using this.

```
def update(name,set,url):
    urllib.urlretrieve(url,"c:/path/"+set+"/"+url)
```

it is currently working, but the images this code obtains can't be opened. i get a message that says that either i don't have the proper update or the windows viewer can't open it because it doesn't support it

Comment: Have you tried to retrieve from a different server, e.g. an image from Wikipedia or so?

Comment: When you save the image to a file - are you opening it in binary mode?